# How can I get the .mp4 file URL in web page?

Tags: html, video, hyperlink, mp4

I am trying to download the video shown in this link -> 
http://www.worktv.or.kr/prog/preProgramVodView.do?progKey=147&contentCid=416

I tried to view all the HTML codes on the page in Google Chrome, and I can found some lines including the ext .mp4, but I am not sure which one is the the correct file link to get.

How can I get that link?

Answer (score 0):

Run this in the console on the page itself:

```
prompt("Link:", $(".player").find('param').last().val().split("=")[1].substring(0,$(".player").find('param').last().val().split("=")[1].lastIndexOf("&")));
```

Note that the video protocol is `rtmp`, which is a video streaming protocol, so might not eventually be able to download it directly even if you have the link